# How can you stop a thread so that the task running on it stops permanentl?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I have a javafx application. I programmed it such that the application starts with a progress bar  that runs to completion. On completion, The window closes and a login window opens. After you sign in, the login window closes and the main window opens.

But that is not what is happening in my application.

I made a task that runs the progressbar from 0 - 100 and I made the task to run on a Thread. When the task is completed, the window closes and login window opens.

The problem I am encountering is that when I sign in using the login window, the main window opens but the login window didn't close.

I wrote a method to close the login window  when the main window opens, but That didnt work.

Please what am I missing?

This is the task class

```
public class TaskClass implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            try {
                progress.setProgress(i / 100.0);
                Thread.sleep(100);

            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(RunningController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // this is the method that closes the  window on which the progress bar is running
                closed(clos);  
                // this is the method that opens the login
                windowloadwindow("/inventory/management/login/InventoryManagementlogin.fxml", "DeMak Inventory");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This loads the  progress bar on a thread

```
Thread thread;

@FXML
private JFXProgressBar progress; 

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    progress.setProgress(0.0);
    Runnable tasks = new TaskClass();
    thread = new Thread(tasks);
    thread.start();
}
```

After you must have signed in using  the login window, This is meant to happen

```
loadwindow("/inventory/management/ui/Main/main.fxml", "Deemax   Inventory");  // a method that opens the main window  

closed(closew);     // a method that closes the login window
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to synchronize `Platform.runLater()` code and background thread code you could use the `CountDownLatch` Class as following:

```
Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                CountDownLatch sync = new CountDownLatch(1);  
                Platform.runLater(()->{
                    // GUI code
                    // ...
                    // end of GUI code
                    sync.countDown();
                });
                sync.await(); // This method will wait for sync.countDown() to be executed 
                // ...
                // code here will be executed after GUI code has finished
                // ...
                return null;
            }
        };
        Thread thread = new Thread(task);
        thread.start();
```

**But**, instead you can solve your problem much easier like this:

```
Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                final int finalCounter = i;
                Platform.runLater(()->{
                    try {
                        progress.setProgress(finalCounter / 100.0);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Logger.getLogger(RunningController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                });
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void succeeded() {
            // code here will be executed after the thread had been completed
            Platform.runLater(()->{
                new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION, "Thread Succeeded!").show();
            });
            closed(clos);      // this is the method that closes the  window on which the progress bar is running
            loadwindow("/inventory/management/login/InventoryManagementlogin.fxml", "DeMak Inventory");     // this is the method that opens the login window
            super.succeeded();
        }
        @Override
        protected void failed() {
            Platform.runLater(()->{
                new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR, "Thread Failed!").show();
            });
            super.failed();
        }
    };
    Thread thread = new Thread(task);
    thread.start();
```

This is my closed method

```
         private void closed(Node nor) {
        Stage stage = (Stage)nor.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();
        }
```

This is my node object.... It is a vbox containing an X image

```
  @FXML
private VBox clos;
```

so I pass the node to the method like this.

```
closed(clos);
```

Comment: You can avoid the `Platform.later()` entirely by using `updateProgress(...)` (which can be called from the background thread), and binding the progress bar to the task's progress property. This also has the advantage of intelligently limiting the number of calls to `Platform.runLater()` for you, no matter how frequently you call `updateProgress()`.

Comment: Nikiforos Archakis, I tried it but the login window wont closed after sign in

Comment: James D , I dont really understand what you mean by that

Comment: Show the code of the `closed` method. Also where do you declare/keep track of `clos` object?

Comment: But where is the node object you are passing? Where do you store it and how do you access it?